# Chartjs reverse bars when negative values Add IndexLabaels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to get a bar like in the image below using Chat.js

what I want to get is a bar with  negative values in the Y ax, hide the values of Xaxe and display the values of each bar (-19,9 and -26,8) [see image][1]

-How can I display the index labels as shown in the image?
-If I display the grille I lose the Xaxe above how can I fix that

Any help is much appreciated

```js
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


    // Global Options
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';


    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels:["5", "10"],
        datasets:[{
       
          data:[ -19.9, -26.8],
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)'            
          ],
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'#777',
          hoverBorderWidth:3,
          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
        }]
      },
      

      options:{
        responsive: true,
        title:{ display:true, text:'PAS',   fontSize:25 },
        legend:{
          display:false,
          position:'right',
          labels:{
            fontColor:'#000'
          }
        },
        layout:{
          padding:{
            left:50,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:0
          }
        },
    
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{

                stacked: false,
                barThickness: 30,  // number (pixels) or 'flex'
                maxBarThickness: 30, // number (pixels)
                ticks:{
                     reverse: true,
                     beginAtZero: true,
              },
               gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
              
              ticks:{
                     
                     beginAtZero: true,
              },


            }]

        }


      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="containerchart" style="position:absolute; width:300px; height:240px;">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="position:absolute; width:300px; height:240px;"></canvas>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="containerchart" style="position:absolute; width:300px; height:240px;">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="position:absolute; width:300px; height:240px;"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript code

````
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


    // Global Options
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';


    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels:["5", "10"],
        datasets:[{
       [enter image description here][2]
          data:[ -19.9, -26.8],
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)'            
          ],
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'#777',
          hoverBorderWidth:3,
          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
        }]
      },
      tooltips: {
           callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
            var datasetLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
            var xLabel = Math.abs(t.xLabel);
            return datasetLabel + ': ' + xLabel;
         }
      }
        },

      options:{
        responsive: true,
        title:{ display:true, text:'PAS',   fontSize:25 },
        legend:{
          display:false,
          position:'right',
          labels:{
            fontColor:'#000'
          }
        },
        layout:{
          padding:{
            left:50,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:0
          }
        },
    
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{

                stacked: false,
                barThickness: 30,  // number (pixels) or 'flex'
                maxBarThickness: 30, // number (pixels)
                ticks:{
                     reverse: true,
                     beginAtZero: true,
              },
               gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                },
              ticks:{
                     
                     beginAtZero: true,
              },
              

            }]

        }


      }
    });

  </script>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaSjK.png
````

Comment: What image below?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaSjK.png   ...It hasn't displayed ! sorry